# What does "Super User requires external JavaScript from another domain" mean?

Tags: support

I got the following error message while viewing a question on Super User. It appeared on top of the page.

> Super User requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is
>   blocked or failed to load.

This is the first time it happened. Is this something I should be concerned about? What does it mean? Do I have to activate JavaScript in the browser or something?

I have seen others having similar errors on Stack Overflow Meta, but not with this exact message.

Comment: Did you recently block some? Or can you view which ones you're blocking?

Comment: @random I believe I was viewing following question: http://superuser.com/questions/433524/is-there-a-windows-utility-to-scale-windows-on-the-screen To me, the page appeared to be normal and loaded. What should I be looking for? But what domain? What other domain is it talking about? What kind of request? Is it talking about loading related questions on the right side, or maybe some ads?

Comment: @Sammy Are you using a browser extension such as Adblock or NoScript? Stack Exchange uses a [content delivery network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), which hosts static files such as images and scripts.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need read the part about what else you need to allow

Comment: Make sure that if you use an adblocker, you disable it on all the Stack Exchange domains. Since you have >200 rep, you only see minimal advertising anyways, almost all of which is in-house ads for other SE sites, community promotion ads, etc. We've had problems in the past with people getting Javascript errors when using ad blockers.

Comment: JavaScript is enabled, cookies are enabled. According to the http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help messaging is OK, storage is OK, Iframes are OK, Referrer is OK, JavaScript is OK. No websockets are used according to websocketstest.com. This error appeared like a live update message. How do I make sure that sites like sstatic.net or googleapis.com are accessible? There is no AdBlocker installed, but "block pop-up windows" is enabled in browser settings. Could it have been just a bad connection?

Comment: *Are you using endless pages from FastestChrome?*